# Gradle cannot find JAVA_HOME @Linux Mint

Tags: java, android, linux, gradle

I use Android Studio und if i run a app, Gradle cannot find JAVA_HOME

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>     Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.

But JAVA_HOME is set:

> alexader@alexander-mint ~ $ echo $JAVA_HOME

returns

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

What do i wrong?

Comment: What are the contents of Your /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/ dir?

Comment: Here is the filelist:

bin ; javafx-src.zip ; man ; THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt ; COPYRIGHT ; jre ; README.html ; THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt ; db ;    lib ; release ; include ; LICENSE ; src.zip

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME seems fine. Check if java compiler is working properly by executing 'javac' in terminal

Comment: If i run javac in terminal, it outputs the help message from javac with all possible arguments.

Comment: Everything seems fine! dont know what the error is about. Last is you can try to change the JAVA_HOME location to /usr/lib/jvm

Comment: unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: Then all you can do is remove jdk completely and setup again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your JAVA_HOME seems to work well, have a look at your Project Structure (Shortcut: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S). Here you can define the location of your JDK. Sometimes this path is "wrong".